# Adding Visual States to a Data Template in Windows 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, datatemplate

I am trying to add a Mouse Over effect to my Windows 8 application. Specifically I'm trying to add it to DataTemplates bound to a GridView. However, Currently, nothing is happening, I've tried to follow the Microsoft tutorials but most of those are either out of date or for different versions of XAML.

My code looks like this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="GameTileTemplate">
    <Grid x:Name="grid" Width="173" Height="173" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" >
        <Grid.Clip>
            <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,173,173"/>
        </Grid.Clip>
        <Image Grid.RowSpan="3" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
        <Grid x:Name="DataPanel" Margin="-173,0,0,0" Grid.RowSpan="3" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Width="346" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="173">
            <!--There is more here-->
        </Grid>
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStateGroup">
                <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                <VisualState x:Name="PointerEntered">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation From="1" To="0" Duration="00:00:02" 
                             Storyboard.TargetName="DataPanel" 
                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                        </DoubleAnimation>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

The Opacity of my DataPanel does not change. Do I need some other code somewhere? The Microsoft Tutorial was for a ControlTemplate, is this causing the error since my Template is a DataTemplate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Xaml you provided in your question is not going to work on its own. Simply defining visual states is not enough. You also need some kind of code to call [VisualStateManager.GoToState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.visualstatemanager.gotostate).

In your particular case solution is not to add visual states to `DataTemplate`, but to create custom template for [GridViewItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.gridviewitem.aspx). In general `GridViewItem` is responsible for decorating elements inside the GridView with common pointer, selection, drag and drop states.

Answer (score 4):

Add UserControl balise it works, (don't know why)

```
 <DataTemplate x:Key="GameTileTemplate">
<UserControl>
<Grid x:Name="grid" Width="173" Height="173" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" >
        <Grid.Clip>
....

...
 </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: You, Sir, are a genius!