# UWP XAML ListView Nested UI on PointerOver

Tags: xaml, listview, uwp, uwp-xaml

I want to create a ListView where the ListViewItems have nested buttons next to the label, which only are shown on PointerOver. That's the DataTemplate I created for this. I tried it with VisualStateManager, but that doesn't work...

So the question is: What's the best pure-XAML way to do that? (or at least a working way would suffice ;) )

Thanks!

```
<DataTemplate x:Name="aUITodoListViewDataTemplate" x:DataType="a:aTodo">
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" PointerEntered="Grid_PointerEntered" PointerExited="Grid_PointerExited">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <!-- creates a grid with three columns, the first so wide as needed, and the second two in a 7/1 ratio-->
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="70*" MaxWidth="500" MinWidth="100"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <!-- First is the actual label -->
        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name}" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" />

        <!-- the middle column is for spacing -->

        <!-- the last column is for the buttons -->
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="2" Orientation="Horizontal" x:Name="buttonGroup">
            <Button>A</Button>
            <Button>B</Button>
            <Button>C</Button>
        </StackPanel>

        <!-- The visual states -->
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="buttonGroup" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible" />
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.333" Value="Collapsed" />
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="buttonGroup" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed" />
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.333" Value="Visible" />
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](https://sanje2v.wordpress.com/2016/03/30/uwp-custom-control-expandable-row-listview/)?

Comment: Not really, but actually its interesting too ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it work by providing a custom control template for `ListViewItem`. For example:

```
<ListView
    ItemsSource="{Binding Data, ElementName=self}"
    Grid.Row="1"
    SelectionChanged="OnSelectionChanged"
    x:Name="listView">
    <ListView.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                        <Grid Background="Pink" x:Name="grid" DataContext="{TemplateBinding DataContext}">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="90" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ContentPresenter />
                            <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal" x:Name="buttonGroup" Visibility="Collapsed">
                                <Button>A</Button>
                                <Button>B</Button>
                                <Button>C</Button>
                            </StackPanel>
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed" />
                                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                        <VisualState.Setters>
                                            <Setter Target="buttonGroup.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                            <Setter Target="grid.Background" Value="Orange" />
                                        </VisualState.Setters>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled" />
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListView.Resources>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

For context, my toy model object looks like this:

```
public class Data
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

...and the page itself (named `self`) exposes the following collection property:

```
public Data[] Data { get; set; } =
    {
        new Data { Name = "One" },
        new Data { Name = "Two" },
        new Data { Name = "Three" },
    };
```

Note that you can't bind to your data model from within the `ControlTemplate`, hence the `DataTemplate` with a `TextBlock` bound to `Name`, and the `ContentPresenter` in the `ControlTemplate`. Conversely, if you want to use the VSM from the `DataTemplate`, you need to set states programatically.

[Here is a related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12903791/adding-visual-states-to-a-data-template-in-windows-8).

The result is really ugly and looks as follows (with the mouse over "Two"):

[image]